# What are the (statistically) normal pH levels in the most-outer part of human sexual organs?

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, skin, sexual-reproduction, ph

What are the (statistically) normal pH values of the outer skin/epidermis of human sex organs (groin/crotch) in the male and female? e.g male testes, female vulva, male glans, the enveloping epiderm, etc. I was trying to find information to no avail.

Edit:

I googled different terms, like anatomical ph index map of the body, and couldn’t find any ph data about specific anatomical structures.

When I googled, I read through reiterations that the body has neutral ph mostly. Again, nothing anatomically specific.

Due to the ‘unique’ per structure microbiome, it does make sense to foresee a different ph, more to the acidic scale.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Bio.SE! Could you provide a clearer indication of where you've already searched and what information you *did* learn along the way? We as that question askers not only *do* background research of their own, but that they also *demonstrate* it. Please update your question using the edit button and add additional detail about your research process thus far.

Comment: Can you explain why you would expect the values to differ from those in the skin at other parts of the body? This would provide context for your question. Otherwise it appears rather strange and is likely to be ignored.

Comment: @David I don't know if this is related or not, but recently a rumor began circulating on the Internet saying that women's vaginal areas are more acidic than the stomach. I wonder if that is why this question is being asked. Ironically, I was just thinking about asking this question... Beat me to it lol

Comment: @L.B. — "A rumour began circulating on the internet". I vote to close.

Comment: @David still would be interesting to know if there's any merit

Comment: @L.B. — I would imagine that three days' silence tells its own story.

Comment: @David, the question makes no attempt to ask about a personal medical question, so voting to close as such doesn't seem appropriate. It also doesn't seem strange for someone to ask this fairly straightforward question given the different environments, bacteria, etc. that these sex organs are associated with compared to the rest of the body. I vote to keep open, and I ask that you more patiently judge people's posts.

Comment: Hi, @theforestecologist I used google with difference keywords, for instance, I just can’t seem to find a ‘map’ of some sort of the human ph index presuming such a map even exists in biology books. I just can’t find any ph data about specific anatomical structures.

Comment: @Ryan, for the sake of making your question more robust and assuaging other users' concerns, I recommend editing your question by including a rationale for why you think the pH is different. I would think a slightly more drawn out form of your last comment (perhaps with an additional explanation of why you think the groin would have different pH) would suffice. Thanks.

Comment: @theforestecologist — In relation to your request, may I say that I read your original personally offensive comment before either the moderators or you removed it. You should therefore know what is required before I respond to that request or any future comments you might make on my posts.

Comment: I might suggest googling "normal vaginal pH", "normal urethral pH", and "normal skin pH". This will get you better google results than your prior search strategy.